# Fancybox loading only once

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Currently I am working on a wordpress project and in order to achieve a popup I am using the fancy box wordpress plugin.

It is working but only for once.And when I click again It is loading the entire page into the pop up instead of just the div.

In console I saw a message and making a guess here that It might be the problem but still no solution. Here is the console message that I got **"synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated"**...

What could be the reason?

In order to check it on live please visit the website here:

http://thejobupdates.com/pt/visbeennew/#serviceCntr

and click on the button that says klik heir

**Code:**

**HTML:**

**Anchor tag:**

```
<a href="#mapModal" class="lMap"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/arrow3.png" />Klik hier</a>
```

**Target div:**

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="mapModal">
        <div class="mapModalTitle">
            <h3>SERVING EUROPE <br /><span>DAILY COOL, FRESH & FROZEN</span></h3>
        </div>
        <?php build_i_world_map(1); ?>        
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(".lMap").fancybox({
    'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    onCleanup: function() {
      var myContent = this.href;
      $(myContent).unwrap();
      console.log("Element was clean");
    }
});
```

Comment: Share your binding code , otherwise we can't help you

Comment: You will get plenty of links when you paste the error message in **[`google`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=synchronous+xmlhttprequest+on+the+main+thread+is+deprecated&oq=synchronous+xmlhttprequest+on+the+main+thread+is+deprecated&aqs=chrome..69i57.577j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)**.. Put some effort on searching for answer and then come with specific problem for which you don't find any proper solution.. And honestly speaking when I did as you said in your `url` I got in console which read **"Element was clean"**

Comment: I did not add the code as I thought the code was correct. And also I did some research and after I tried most of them with no result, I came through a post that mentioned the answer that this problem might happen due to jquery version being used. so did I asked the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

You are using version 1.3.4 of fancybox. This all seems like a bug to me. 
Try updating to fancybox to version 2.x -> http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

### Original anwser

- this didnt solve the issue, see comments.

It's happening because of your onCleanup function:

```
onCleanup: function() {
  var myContent = this.href;
  $(myContent).unwrap(); <--- // this removes the modal.
  console.log("Element was clean");
}
```

when you close the modal, the `onCleanup` is called. 
It picks up your `<div id="mapModal">` and removes it.
I don't know why you need to have it there but, remove it and everything should work.

you can see that the element doesnt exist if you drop this into console before and after opening the modal for the first time.

```
jQuery("#mapModal")
```

at first it will return the div, on second time it doesn't find anything.
more on unwarp here https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: I did not have it in my code, got a suggestion from someone and had it there. Yes you did point it out that html is being removed due to the unwrap. But even if I remove it does not work. Please check the website: http://thejobupdates.com/pt/visbeennew/

Comment: I did remove the code you mentioned but still no help

Comment: @KiranKumarDash looked at it a bit more but, could not find anything more, it's just very weird. Would it be a problem for you to update to [fancybox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)? Currently you are using 1.3.4

Comment: I think unwrap is not removing the html markup here.